# How to position children with respect to parent in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am using HTML 5 with CSS 3. The scenario is like this.

```
<div style="margin-top: 50px; background-color: red; padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px; width: 100%">
<span>This text must be in center of div</span>
<a href="somepage.html"><img src="/image.jpg" alt="This image must be on left side of div"/></a>
</div>
```

The text and image must be in single line. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Example

[image: Example]

To position an element with respect to its parent, you give the parent any position value besides `static` (generally `relative`) and the child `position: absolute`.

In keeping with your inline CSS...

```
<div style="margin-top: 50px; background-color: red; padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px; width: 100%; text-align: center; position: relative;">
    This text must be in center of div
    <img src="/image.jpg" alt="This image must be on left side of div" style="position: absolute; left: 0;"/>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/saSMm/).

However you should consider using classes, ids and an external stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? I edited the code based on your comment. The caveat is that the line-height of the P tag must be set to the height of the div in order to get the P to center vertically as well as horizontally.

```
    <style>
.myDiv{
    background-image: url('../pathToImage/image.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center left;   
    margin-top: 50px; 
    background-color: red; 
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 250px;
}
.myDiv P
{
    line-height:250px;

}
</style>
<div class="myDiv">
        <p>This text must be in center of div.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks both yours and Alex's solution seem to work. Since Alex replied earlier. I'll accept his answer and mark yours as useful.

Comment: I updated my solution because the text wasn't centered vertically as well as horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

SPAN and IMG are both inline elements so they should be appear next to each other by default. If you want the IMG to appear on the left and the SPAN text after it...

```
<img /><span />
```

Comment: The issue appears in central and left positioning